# How to use bindings of multiple instances to update display?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is a difficult question to ask. In my XAML file, I have multiple bindings of the form:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding A.B.C}"
```

By a list selection, B can be changed to another instance. When so changed, I am manually running through each of the bindings with

```
OnPropertyChanged("C")
```

in the view model to refresh the display. This is very tedious for a large display.

Is it possible to update "B" alone and force display update without manually going through each of the bindings?

TIA

Comment: could you clarify more please !, what does A.B.C mean ?

Comment: Several options: 1) update all bindings with `OnPropertyChanged("")` 2) map `C` with dedicated property in viewmodel and call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C))` 3) Do something to call `OnPropertyChanged(someName)` in a loop, where `someName` is generated (using reflection or by a list of items to update). In MVVM mapping is preferable to avoid such nestings (it's tedious though).

Comment: @SamTheDev C is final property, e.g. a string. A is a class I'm calling an Editor, e.g. PrimaryInsurance. B is the particular insurance quantity being edited.

Comment: @Sinatr So, I guess I'm stuck with  the one-to-one mapping ...yes...tedious. Thanks.

Comment: C is a property of B and B is property of A so you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to every of this classes(properties) so when notification is called from B or C then A will notify too. It's not multiple binding AFAIK (Or this is called like this? But still you bind only one property) .

Comment: @MichalKozak  So change B from a specific instance to something like an ObservableCollection to allow swapping out different B's ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your intentions you have multiple 'Bs' and you want to display their 'C' value. If you bind DataContext={Binding A.B} (or just B - it depends on your Page's DataContext) of your List / DataTemplate / or whatever you have there it should work and as far as you have C property in your B then TextBox={Binding C} will change its value too.

Comment: I wish it were quit that simple. Actually, the DataContext will need to remain A and B is imported data from a WCF service, i.e., no inherent INotifyPropertyChanged. So ultimately, I end up with a one-to-one mapping at some point. Good answer though. Thanks.